# Rendering entry titles in dropdown using Stash

Tags: stash

I'm trying to render a list of entry titles into a drop menu using Stash. However, I get no results. I modeled my solution using another thread here, but no go.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
{exp:stash:set_product_list name="product_list_name" parse_tags="yes"}
   {exp:channel:entries channel="product_profiles"}
        {stash:product_title} {title} {/stash:product_title}
        {stash:product_entry_id} {entry_id} {/stash:product_entry_id}
   {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_product_list}
```

```
<!--initial display field is blank-->
     <option value="" selected></option>

<!--values show in dropdown--->
     {exp:stash:get_product_list name="product_list_name" unique="yes"}
        <option value="{product_entry_id}">{product_title}</option>
     {/exp:stash:get_product_list}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of the stash tags is slightly wrong. It should be `{exp:stash:set_list}` not `{exp:stash:set_product_list}`. The same applies to your usage of the `{exp:stash:get_list}` tag.

Updating your code to the following should work correctly:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="product_list_name" parse_tags="yes"}
   {exp:channel:entries channel="product_profiles"}
      {stash:product_title} {title} {/stash:product_title}
      {stash:product_entry_id} {entry_id} {/stash:product_entry_id}
   {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

<select name="product_select">
    <!--initial display field is blank-->
    <option value="" selected></option>

    <!--values show in dropdown-->
    {exp:stash:get_list name="product_list_name" unique="yes"}
        <option value="{product_entry_id}">{product_title}</option>
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
</select>
```